# Next Image Link to wp_get_attachment_link() Function

Tags: php, wordpress

Can i add **next image** url to the wp_get_attachment_link()?

in post-template.php, it says:

```
return apply_filters( 'wp_get_attachment_link', "<a href='" . esc_url( $url ) . "'>
$link_text</a>", $id, $size, $permalink, $icon, $text );
```

and i want to change esc_url( $url ) that part; the url.

but i couldnt find how to find next-previous image links to add..

do you have any idea?